# AWS EMR Cluster Streaming Step: Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I am trying to set up a trivial EMR job to perform word counting of massive text files, stored in `s3://__mybucket__/input/`. I am unable to correctly add the first of the two required streaming steps (the first is map input to `wordSplitter.py`, reduce with an `IdentityReducer` to temporary storage; second step is map the contents of this secondary storage using `/bin/wc/`, and reduce with an `IdentityReducer` yet again).

This is the (failure) description of the first step:

```
Status:FAILED
Reason:S3 Service Error.
Log File:s3://aws-logs-209733341386-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/j-2XC5AT2ZP48FJ/steps/s-1SML7U7CXRDT5/stderr.gz
Details:Exception in thread "main" com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 7799087FCAE73457), S3 Extended Request ID: nQYTtW93TXvi1G8U4LLj73V1xyruzre+uSt4KN1zwuIQpwDwa+J8IujOeQMpV5vRHmbuKZLasgs=
JAR location: command-runner.jar
Main class: None
Arguments: hadoop-streaming -files s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py -mapper wordSplitter.py -reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer -input s3://__mybucket__/input/ -output s3://__mybucket__/output/
Action on failure: Continue
```

This is the command being sent to the hadoop cluster:

```
JAR location : command-runner.jar
Main class : None
Arguments : hadoop-streaming -mapper s3a://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py -reducer aggregate -input s3a://__my_bucket__/input/ -output s3a://__my_bucket__/output/
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution here is likely very easy.

Instead of `s3://` use `s3a://` as a scheme for your job accessing the bucket.
See [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), the `s3://` scheme is deprecated and requires the bucket in question to be exclusive to your Hadoop data. Quote from the above doc link:

> This filesystem requires you to dedicate a bucket for the filesystem -
>   you should not use an existing bucket containing files, or write other
>   files to the same bucket. The files stored by this filesystem can be
>   larger than 5GB, but they are not interoperable with other S3 tools.

Comment: I got the same error. Bad Request `Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 4C4C5B2DBA095F5C`

Comment: @Skyler hmm maybe to help me narrow this down. Are you able to copy said file to your HDFS via distcp ?

Comment: I have no idea what that is. I am not interfacing with Hadoop directly. I'm using the AWS console

Comment: @Skyler oh, can you share the code for interacting with the AWS console (best if you add it to the question before the error imo)?